# Car Clutch issue after repair Vauxhall Zafira 2007

Tags: transmission, clutch, manual-transmission, vauxhall, zafira

I replaced the gearbox cable at mechanic and after that the clutch box is not working properly. All the gears are very loose and the first gear sometimes works as a reverse gear but the reverse gear works fine. The car has no first gear for pickup. What’s the problem and how do I fix it?
My car is a 2007 Vauxhall Zafira 1.6L Life.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you mean by you "replaced the gearbox cable at mechanic"? If you had a mechanic do the work, you should probably complain to the mechanic.

Comment: This sounds like the cable or linkage is badly adjusted or loose - take it back to the mechanic you mention - or better yet consider a different or better one.

Answer (score 2):

As Solar Mike says it sounds like the linkage between the gear lever and gearbox selector rod has been refitted but not adjusted in the correct position. Normally you would make a note or mark this rods possition before disconnecting it from the gearbox.

You can get it back into its correct position, however if you have no reference marks on the selector shaft you'll just have to take your time trying to adjust it until you can select all the gears. It would help if you had someone sit in the car to help you check for gears whilst you made small adjustments to the rods position.

A starting point would be to put the stubby gearbox selector shaft in what would be its fifth gear position, then place the gear lever in what would be its fifth gear position and try it. You can make small adjustments if necessary until you can get all gears.

Comment: Yes - a game that can be played for hours without the correct info...